# Importing a .sql file in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have just started learning SQL and I'm having some difficulties to import my sql file in python.

The .sql file is in my desktop, as well is my .py file.

That's what I tried so far:

```
import codecs
from codecs import open
import pandas as pd
sqlfile = "countries.sql"
sql = open(sqlfile, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read()
pd.read_sql_query("SELECT name FROM countries")
```

But I got the following message error:

```
TypeError: read_sql_query() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'
```

I think I have to create some kind of connection, but I can't find a way to do that. Converting my data to an ordinary pandas DataFrame would help me a lot.

Thank you

Comment: What `sql` variable used for in posted code? What is `countries.sql` file? Seems to be sqlite database, so it should be handled with sqlite-client. For more details https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-pandas-databases/

Answer (score 1):

You need a database connection. I don't know what SQL flavor are you using, but suppose you want to run your query in SQL server

```
import pyodbc
con = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='yourserverurl', database='yourdb', trusted_connection=yes)
```

then pass the connection instance to pandas

```
pd.read_sql_query("SELECT name FROM countries", con)
```

more about pyodbc [here](https://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/)

And if you want to query an SQLite database

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('pathto/example.db')
```

More about sqlite [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code snippet taken from https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-pandas-databases/ should help.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("flights.db")
df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from airlines limit 5;", conn)
```

Do not read database as an ordinary file. It has specific binary format and special client should be used.

With it you can create connection which will be able to handle SQL queries. And can be passed to `read_sql_query`.

Refer to documentation often https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html